# How to avoid implicit type conversion from VARCHAR to VARCHAR2 using Hibernate?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

Some colleagues came up with a problem, where they recognized slow execution times for a query and they found out that an index is not used because of a implicit type conversion.

The table has an attribut `kgb_uuid` for storing an UUID. The column is defined as `VARCHAR2` and has an index on it to search a row by the UUID.

The related field in the entity is defined as `String`. According to the Hibernate docs Hibernate should transform this string to `VARCHAR2` on Oracle databases and therefore the index should be used.

But this not the case as the logs show:

> [9/2/19 11:56:07:610 CEST] 00000177 SystemOut     O
>   2019-09-02T11:56:07,610 TRACE [ebContainer : 3]
>   i.b.e.b.c.TraceInterceptor;log;;41 - entry method
>   [checkEindeutigeUUID] in class [MyDAO] with params (MyEntity@b14745f9)
>
> [9/2/19 11:56:07:688 CEST] 00000177 SQL           Z
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger logStatement select
>   count(mytab0_.KGB_NR) as col_0_0_ from MYENTITYTABLE mytab_ where
>   mytab_.KGB_UUID=? and mytab_.EKN_NR=?
>
> [9/2/19 11:56:07:688 CEST] 00000177 BasicBinder   Z org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder
>   bind binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] -
>   795BF3B98D879358E0531C03A90ABF0A [9/2/19 11:56:07:688 CEST] 00000177
>   BasicBinder   Z org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder bind
>   binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - 1

As seen the String value is bound as `VARCHAR` not as `VARCHAR2`, resulting in an implicit type conversion by the database and not using the index, as seen in the OEM (It's the original German message from the OEM):

> Das Prädikat SYS_OP_C2C("mytab_"."KGB_UUID")=:B1, das in Zeilen-ID 3
>   des Ausführungsplans benutzt wird, enthält eine Konvertierung des
>   impliziten Datentyps auf der indexierten Spalte "KGB_UUID". Diese
>   Konvertierung des impliziten Datentyps verhindert, dass der Optimizer
>   Indizes auf Tabelle "MYENTITYTABLE" effizient nutzt.

It says that the predicate `SYS_OP_C2C("mytab_"."KGB_UUID")=:B1` is used and this contains an conversation of the implicit attribute type of the indexed base column `KGB_UUID` and that this conversation of the implicit type prevents that the optimizer can use indizies of the table `MYENTITYTABLE` efficiently.

We have fixed issue using a functional index on the table, but we are still wondering why Hibernate provides an data type which is obviously not `VARCHAR2`.

System:

- Hibernate 4.2.21 with Hibernate Dialect Oracle10g (which is compatible up to 12 according to docs)
- Oracle 12.2 (don't now exactly, I think 12.2, but maybe only 12.1)

The Hibernate version can't be upgraded as it is the last version that can be used with JPA 2.0, which is part of JavaEE 6 supported by Websphere Process Server 8.5.

The (shortend) Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MYENTITYTABLE")
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  // out commented the sequence generator 
  @Column(name="KGB_NR")
  private long kgbNr;

  @Column(name="KGB_UUID")
  private String kgbUuid; // <<== DEFINED AS STRING!

  //bi-directional many-to-one association to Ekistnutzer
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="EKN_NR")
  private EkistnutzerEntity ekistnutzer;

  // Other attributes not related in problem
}
```

The DAO method

```
public int checkEindeutigeUUID(MyEntity myEntity) throws Exception {

    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Long> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Long.class);
    ParameterExpression<String> kgbUuidParam = criteriaBuilder.parameter(String.class, "kgbUuid");
    ParameterExpression<EkistnutzerEntity> ekistnutzerParam = criteriaBuilder.parameter(EkistnutzerEntity.class,
        "ekistnutzer");
    Root<MyEntity> root = query.from(MyEntity.class);
    query.select(criteriaBuilder.count(root));
    query.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("kgbUuid"), kgbUuidParam),
        criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("ekistnutzer"), ekistnutzerParam));

    try {
      TypedQuery<Long> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query);
      typedQuery.setParameter("ekistnutzer", myEntity.getEkistnutzer());
      typedQuery.setParameter("kgbUuid", myEntity.getKgbUuid());

      return typedQuery.getSingleResult().intValue();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

Comment: If you see a function call like `SYS_OP_C2C("mytab_"."KGB_UUID")=:B1` in the plan I am pretty certain, that Oracle injected that while rewriting the plan. Turn on SQL logging in Hibernate, and you will probably see, that Hibernate did **not** generate that code. I have seen this happen quite frequently with Oracle. Might be related to the setting of [cursor_sharing](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-455358F8-D657-49A2-B32B-13A1DC53E7D2.htm#REFRN10025)

Comment: Unrelated, but: storing a UUID as a `varchar` is not a good idea to begin with. It would be more efficient to store it as a `RAW(16)`

Comment: Are you sure this is a `VARCHAR` problem and not an `NVARCHAR` problem?  `VARCHAR` is simply an alias for `VARCHAR2`, and in my simple testing there is no conversion between the two.  However, when I try to compare `VARCHAR2` with `NVARCHAR2`, then the `SYS_OP_C2C` shows up.

Comment: @JonHeller Personally I'm not sure as the problem was only described to me. I have passed your comment to my collegues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to extend the default `StringType` and override the `sqlType` property and supply the new Hibernate Type to your entity attribute via the [`@Type`](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-a-custom-basic-type-using-hibernate-usertype/) annotation.

Most likely the `VARCHAR2` mapping comes via the Oracle Hibernate Dialect, so you should not probably override the default Dialect mapping as there might be columns rightfully using `VARCHAR2`.

So, the custom Hibernate Type gives you control and allows you to use it only for the `VARCHAR` columns.

Comment: Thank you. I'll handle the answer to my collegues. If they tell me, that it helped I'll accept the answer. But I don't know if they will realy try it as they definied the functional index.